# I want to display array elements in a table row such that each row contains 3 elements

Tags: javascript

Thanks for your answer. what if I have to display 3  in  .I want to iterate the loop to display 3 elements in each row.

```
table= '<table>';
for(i=1;i<=arr.length;i++) {
    table= '<tr>';
                if(arr[i]==undefined)
                    {
                    table += '</tr>';
                    break;
                    }
                else {
                    table+='<td>'+arr[i]+'</td>';
                    //document.write(arr[i] + ' ');
                }
                if(i%3 == 0) {
                    table += '</tr>';
                    //document.write('<br />');
                }
}
table += '</table>';
document.write(table);
```

Comment: I see... you are new to javascript and any kind of loops

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what if I have to display 3 <td> in <tr>

Comment: Do you want my answer? I can make one if you want.

Comment: Sir if you do it, it will be a great help for my academics.

Comment: I made the answer... bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You challenged me and... okay that is easy and it's easy to read:

```js
var arr = ['apple','boy','cat','dog','egg','fish','gum','gun','hat','ink','jug','kite','lamb','man'];

var html = [];//like a string builder

html.push('<table>');

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 3){
 html.push('<tr>');
 
 html.push('<td>', arr[i] ,'</td>');
 
 html.push('<td>', arr[i + 1], '</td>');
 
 html.push('<td>', arr[i + 2], '</td>');
 
 html.push('</tr>');
}

html.push('</table>');

document.write(html.join(''));
```

```css
td{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr=['apple','boy','cat','dog','egg','fish','gum','gun','hat','ink','jug','kite','lamb','man'];

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i+=3){
 var row = [];
 row.push(arr[i] || '' ); 
 row.push(arr[i+1] || '' ); 
 row.push(arr[i+2] || '' );
    row.push("<br>"); 
 document.write(row.join(" "))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
var arr=['apple','boy','cat','dog','egg','fish','gum','gun','hat','ink','jug','kite','lamb','man'];
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {   
    if(i != 0 && i%3 === 0) {
     document.write('<br />');
    }
    if(arr[i]==undefined)
        break;
    else {
     document.write(arr[i] + ' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what if I have to display 3 <td> in <tr>